# looping the datasource in imacros

Tags: javascript, loops, datasource, imacros

```
VERSION BUILD=8601111 RECORDER=FX

TAB T=1

SET !ERRORIGNORE YES

SET !DATASOURCE Latian2.csv

SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}}

EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="#messageBoxForm>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV>DIV>DIV>SPAN>SPAN" BUTTON=0

EVENT TYPE=MOUSEDOWN SELECTOR="#messageBoxForm>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV>DIV>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>STRONG" BUTTON=0

EVENT TYPE=MOUSEUP POINT="(629,52)"

EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="#messageBoxForm>DIV>DIV>DIV>SPAN" BUTTON=0

EVENTS TYPE=KEYPRESS SELECTOR="#messageBoxForm>DIV>DIV>DIV>DIV>TEXTAREA" CHARS="{{!COL1}}"

EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="#saveMessageButtons>SPAN:nth-of-type(2)>SPAN:nth-of-type(2)" BUTTON=0
```

-- here is the datas i have in Latian2.csv --

1. testing website a
2. testing website b

With that code i want to loop the data in latian2.csv 6 times and fill the same place in the website, and i set play loops 6 times too in imacros.
yes the code can loops the data, but after it plays for the 3rd times, it only loops line 2. and so on until it ends..

Is there a code that I miss?

How can i fix this?

Comment: The code is fine. Are you sure the CSV is good?

Comment: i dont know.. here is the csv :

Comment: i dont know.. i just write it using notepad++, there are two line there.. line 1. file testing and line 2. file testing and line2.. i dont why the script only looping the 2nd line after it plays the 3rd loop and so on till it end